# Nesting tables of recipes and ingredients in one view

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'd like to figure out how to set up a table where I can search for one recipe and have it display all the ingredients.  If an ingredient is a recipe of it's own (pasta dinner > marinara sauce > tomatoes, basil, etc) I'd like to display that nested in the parent recipe.

```
| Recipe       | Ingredient     |

| Pasta Dinner |                |

|              | Pasta          |
|              | Marinara Sauce |
|              |                | Tomatoes  | 3    |
|              |                | Basil     | 1 cup|
```

I have some flexibilty in the source list but I was thinking this to base it off of.

```
|Pasta Dinner  | Pasta          | 8 oz
|Pasta Dinner  | Marinara Sauce | 8 oz
|Marinara Sauce| Tomatoes       | 3
|Marinara Sauce| Basil          | 1 cup
```

Comment: Sounds delicious. let us know how it turns out. See [Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is good... for a database. Essentially you are doing a:

```
parent | child | attribute1 | attribute2 | attributeN
```

type of table. Which is great because a database can do a hierarchical/recursive query and stitch everything together.

But... you are in Excel, and Excel will hate you if you do this. Your structure is going to need to look like:

```
recipe | ingredient | ingredient of ingredient | ingredient of ingredient of ingredient | ... | amount
pasta dinner | pasta | | | 8oz
pasta dinner | marinara | | | 8oz
pasta dinner | marinara | tomatoes | | 3
pasta dinner | marinara | basil | | 1 cup
```

It will look something like

**DATA**

[image]

**PIVOT**

[image]